# Stop zsh from completing parent directories

Tags: zsh, filenames, autocomplete

I am using zsh with grml's zshrc as a base. As part of my work I access network path regulary (e.g NFS. AFS.)

If I write /a/long/network/path/on/the/other/side/of/the/world press TAB twice it is painfully slow as zsh start searching under /a/ then /a/long /a/long/network etc...

At the same time running ls /a/long/network/path/on/the/other/side/of/the/world returns in a sec. So I would like to tell zsh to stop second guessing me.
(If I write /usr/src/linuxx/ and then press tab it figures out that i wanted /usr/src/linux/ and this is cool however because the network it does me more harm than good). I would like to only autocomplete "at the end" after the last slash.

Sometimes I am using a workaround cd into the directory then use autocompletion. Surely there must be a better way.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This kind of behavior is configured through [styles](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Standard-Styles) (except for a few fundamentals that have options). You'll want to turn off [`path-completion`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-path_002dcompletion_002c-completion-style).

> By default, filename completion examines all components of a path to see if there are completions of that component. For example, `/u/b/z` can be completed to `/usr/bin/zsh`. Explicitly setting this style to false inhibits this behaviour for path components up to the `/` before the cursor

```
zstyle ':completion:*' path-completion false
```

You may want to turn on [`accept-exact-dirs`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-accept_002dexact_002ddirs_002c-completion-style) instead. With `path-completion` left on and `accept-exact-dirs` turned on, zsh will only attempt completion for path components other than the last one if the path doesn't exist.

```
zstyle ':completion:*' accept-exact-dirs true
```

Comment: I see that I just accepted this answer. I think I should have also said: "awesome this is exactly what I need" -ed. thx ;-).

Comment: That is very cool.   What would be the accept-exact-dirs style for bash?   Thanks

Comment: @waterstone Bash's completion is a lot less powerful. It probably doesn't have anything similar.

Comment: zsh path completion on the nfs was painfully slow that I couldn't even use it. After adding the `accept-exact-dirs` it fixed the problem. I had to strace the difference of what zsh and bash were doing and noticed that zsh was trying to stat directories not part of the path I was typing and getting access denied. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks; for me the completion of anything like `cd ../` followed by double tab was absurdly, unusably slow. Killing this feature is a huge performance gain.